# How can I make my discord bot only react on a certain user id?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This does not work it will start spamming the message whenever someone says something

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.id = '655876175616540700') {
    message.reply('test');
  }
});
```

Comment: `=` is for assigning a value to a variable and `==` or `===` is for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`message.author.id = '655876175616540700'` does not do what you want. You should make a comparison with `message.author.id === '655876175616540700'`.

The triple equals operator (===) returns true if operands (both sides) are have the same type AND contain the same value.

The single equal operator (=) is an assignment operator, it will always return true in your `if` statement.